# Excel: Disable cut, copy, but allow paste function in Excel with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have code that disables cut, copy and paste functions in Excel. but I need to allow paste function that be able paste to my excel from other excel (e.g. C3:E10).
Any help will be appreciated

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.OnKey "^c", ""
Application.CellDragAndDrop = False
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
Application.CellDragAndDrop = True
Application.OnKey "^c"
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_WindowActivate(ByVal Wn As Window)
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.OnKey "^c", ""
Application.CellDragAndDrop = False
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_WindowDeactivate(ByVal Wn As Window)
Application.CellDragAndDrop = True
Application.OnKey "^c"
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
Application.OnKey "^c", ""
Application.CellDragAndDrop = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable Copy and Cut on the ribbon, modify the HTML of the Excel workbook with this lines:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui"
onLoad="rxIRibbonUI_onLoad">
   <commands>
     <command idMso="Cut"
      getEnabled="rxshared_getEnabled"
     />
     <command idMso="Copy"
      getEnabled="rxshared_getEnabled"  
     />
     <command idMso="Paste"
      getEnabled="rxshared_getEnabled"  
     />
  </commands>
</customUI>
```

For this, you can use one of these two methods:

1. Use the Custom UI Editor For Microsoft Office program. You have a
   lot of information to work with it on the web, for example in
   https://bettersolutions.com/vba/ribbon/custom-ui-editor.htm
2. Change the Excel workbook extension from `*.xlsm` to `*.xlsm.zip`,
   open this zip file and create a `customUI` folder. In it copy a
   `customUI.xml` file that contains the previous lines. Then
   return the extension to`*.xlsm`

To disable Copy and Cut in the menus and keyboard shortcuts I have used http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=373
in this way:

Copy in `Thisworkbook` this code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    grxIRibbonUI_CutCopyPaste.Invalidate
End Sub

'===================================================================================
'===================================================================================
'http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=373
'===================================================================================
'===================================================================================
 
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    Call ToggleCutCopyAndPaste(False)
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Call ToggleCutCopyAndPaste(True)
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
    Call ToggleCutCopyAndPaste(True)
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call ToggleCutCopyAndPaste(False)
End Sub
```

In a standard module `Module1`:

```
'===================================================================================
'===================================================================================
'http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=373
'===================================================================================
'===================================================================================

Option Explicit
 
Sub ToggleCutCopyAndPaste(Allow As Boolean)
     'Activate/deactivate cut, copy, paste and pastespecial menu items
    Call EnableMenuItem(21, Allow) ' cut
    Call EnableMenuItem(19, Allow) ' copy
    'Call EnableMenuItem(22, Allow) ' paste
    'Call EnableMenuItem(755, Allow) ' pastespecial
     
     'Activate/deactivate drag and drop ability
    Application.CellDragAndDrop = Allow
     
     'Activate/deactivate cut, copy, paste and pastespecial shortcut keys
    With Application
        Select Case Allow
        Case Is = False
            .OnKey "^c", "CutCopyPasteDisabled"
            '.OnKey "^v", "CutCopyPasteDisabled"
            .OnKey "^x", "CutCopyPasteDisabled"
            .OnKey "+{DEL}", "CutCopyPasteDisabled"
            .OnKey "^{INSERT}", "CutCopyPasteDisabled"
        Case Is = True
            .OnKey "^c"
            '.OnKey "^v"
            .OnKey "^x"
            .OnKey "+{DEL}"
            .OnKey "^{INSERT}"
        End Select
    End With
End Sub
 
Sub EnableMenuItem(ctlId As Integer, Enabled As Boolean)
     'Activate/Deactivate specific menu item
    Dim cBar As CommandBar
    Dim cBarCtrl As CommandBarControl
    For Each cBar In Application.CommandBars
        If cBar.Name <> "Clipboard" Then
            Set cBarCtrl = cBar.FindControl(ID:=ctlId, recursive:=True)
            If Not cBarCtrl Is Nothing Then cBarCtrl.Enabled = Enabled
        End If
    Next
End Sub
 
Sub CutCopyPasteDisabled()
     'Inform user that the functions have been disabled
    MsgBox "Sorry!  Cutting, copying and pasting have been disabled in this workbook!"
End Sub
```

In a standard `RibbonModule`:

```
'This module is responsible for managing the HTML code that
'we have created in the Workbook

Option Explicit

Public grxIRibbonUI_CutCopyPaste As IRibbonUI

Public Sub rxIRibbonUI_onLoad(ByRef ribbon As IRibbonUI)
    Set grxIRibbonUI_CutCopyPaste = ribbon
End Sub

Public Sub rxshared_getEnabled(ByRef Control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal)
    Select Case Control.ID
    Case "Cut"
        returnedVal = False
    Case "Copy"
        returnedVal = False
    Case "Paste"
        returnedVal = True
    End Select
    
End Sub
```

Now you just have to save and re-open the Excel workbook and you will see that Cut and Copy are disabled but you can Paste.